# User defined .c and .h file management

Tags: c, .so, .a

I am building a small library of my own *.c & *.h files and am not sure how I should manage them, especially when including them into a project. I'm using Codeblocks on Ubuntu in case that matters. For each .c/.h file pair, I have a Codeblocks project that is a playground where I can modify & test out any changes or newfound bugs.

I'm thinking I should compile the .c into libraries (.a/.so), put them into respective custom 'XXX/bin' and 'XXX/include' folders, and include/link from those locations (add to the PATH).

The other option (which I've been doing for right or wrong) is to add the .c file directly to my project and #include the full path of the .h file (I know this is wrong, but it works).

How do you all manage your .c and .h files?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, both ways (prepare object files and use headers with them when compile program, and add source code and headers to each project with full or relative path) are quite normal. You should choose a way that is convenient for you. I do not know how Codeblocks works, but I suppose that as most IDE it can support dependencies, optimize build time and rebuild libraries (components of complex project) if some files were updated.

My suggestion is to consider some project build tools (project makers) like cmake. You will be able to configure building process for any project and to use different compilers, as well as different compiling options for different projects, while source files (*.c and *.h) storage is unchanged.

Start from [cmake tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/) and other [documentation](https://cmake.org/documentation/)

Of course, at first it will be not easy to deal with the makefile syntax, but when you get used to it you will realize how much it's convenient.

Comment: Thank you. You're right about cmake, I saw tried to decipher a cmake file once and it was a nightmare! I suppose I should take a run at it with a tutorial.

Comment: You should try and you can ask questions about cmake when issues arise

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to include headers from their exact source, on a linux platform at least.

assume that you put your *.h in /usr/include you can just use

```
#include "/usr/include/*.h"
```

w/o moving your source files you can add the same chunk of code to every new sources you write, but VolAnd's above mentioned suggestions are probably more standard ways of managing.